# Start interactive function definition from shell-script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, function

Using zsh or bash, I want to run a script that may prompt the user for multiple commands and store them as a function, however I'm finding that `eval "function $FNCNAME() {"` or `echo "function $FNCNAME() {" | zsh -is` is not valid unless typed directly since the script will not wait for more input before either continuing to the next line or exiting.

How do I block the script process while accepting user input, and continue only when the user has concluded the function definition with a final (unquoted) `}`?

Requirements are:

- The shells own context aware autocomplete functionality is active.
- The script should not immediately execute the deferred commands but should be able to call or print the definition of the new function

This question is limited to a general piping and interaction problem. I am not asking for:

- How to provide prewritten commands to a script in any way.
- How to provide "the best user experience" or how to improve it.
- Why I should not solve this problem and do something else instead.

Comment: Note that this is a really, really bad idea. Prompting for input is sometimes the right approach, but very rarely and asking for _commands_ is certainly not a good use of prompts. It is too easy to have typos, which are hard to fix and even harder to notice. If I give 5 commands and realize the 1st had a typo, I need to redo everything. Why not make your script take a file as input and your users can have the commands in the file instead?

Comment: Fair criticism. I have updated the question with an extensive "why". Inconsequential to this more general (and easier) Q&A, my real usage area is a zsh zle accept-line override with new syntax' potential to wrap functions with additional behavior.

Comment: I honestly don't know if what you want is possible. I suspect it either isn't, or it will be absurdly complex. I still think the whole thing is misguided: allowing your users to enter the name of a file with the commands which they have prepared outside your script allows them to use the shell's autocompletion natively. You are first restricting your users and forcing them to use a cumbersome and error-prone approach (manually typing things) and then want to get the benefit of autocompletion etc, which you can get by simply _not_ forcing them to manually enter commands in the first place.

Comment: I suspect the solution to be just a correct way of prepending/injecting 'fnc() {' to stdin, starting a subshell and appending 'typeset -f fnc; exit' for capturing output.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Give them an editor window where they can complete all they want.

Comment: It seems the Y was a big distraction. I have updated again, only focusing on the actual important parts.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, it could be something like:

```
make-function() {
  local psvar=$1
  local line= body=
  print -ru2 Please enter the definition of the $psvar function, one line at a time, terminate with an empty line.
  while
    line=
    vared -p '%v> ' line
    [[ -n $line ]]
  do
    body+=$line$'\n'
  done
  functions[$psvar]=$body
}
```

Then for example:

```
$ make-function f
Please enter the definition of the f function, one line at a time, terminate with an empty line.
f> echo test
f> return 42
f>
$ f
test
$ echo $?
42
$ functions f
f () {
        echo test
        return 42
}
```

You could also just do:

```
vared 'functions[f]'
```

To edit the body of the `f` function in the line editor. Note that <kbd>Enter</kbd> leaves the editor and you need <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> like in bash's readline) to enter a literal newline in the  body of the function as usual.

`vared` (variable editor) is a builtin that invokes the zsh line  editor (zle) to edit the contents of a variable, `$functions` is a special associative array that maps function names to a representation of the code in their body.

In `bash`, you can do something approaching by using `IFS= read -rep "$psvar> " line` where `-e` uses readline to edit `$line`, and you can use `eval "$psvar() { $body; }"` to create the function from the name and body.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat ./tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

fncname='foo'

printf 'List commands, terminated with Control-D\n' >&2

{
    printf '%s () {\n' "$fncname"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '\t%s\n' "$line"
    done
    printf '}\n'
} > "$tmp" &&
. "$tmp"

declare -f "$fncname"

"$fncname"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
List commands, terminated with Control-D
echo 'hello'
date
echo 'world'
        <- I hit Control-D here
foo ()
{
    echo 'hello';
    date;
    echo 'world'
}
hello
Wed Jan  3 15:48:38 CST 2024
world
```